# Select cells with same value with variable

Tags: vba, excel

Let's assume I have in xls a range filled like this:

```
ROW 1 |1|s|d|f|g|

ROW 2 |2|d|k|o|p|

ROW 3 |1|a|x|y|z|
```

I already have the code (vba) to work (parse data) on each row and put it into a txt file, but I'm not able to work **only** with rows that have, for example, "1" in the first column.

Almost tried most of the suggestion here posted without any luck...

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

lastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
SetValSrcNat = ""

Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
On Error GoTo fileexists
Set stream = fs.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\luciano.vigano\Documents   \prova.txt", False, True)


For elabrow = 6 To lastRow


valInterface = Cells(elabrow, 3).Value
valProto = Cells(elabrow, 8).Value
valSrc = Cells(elabrow, 9).Value
    If valSrc = "host" Then
        valSrc = Cells(elabrow, 10)
    Else
        valSrc = Cells(elabrow, 9).Value & " " & Cells(elabrow, 10)
    End If
valSrcNat = Cells(elabrow, 11).Value
    If valSrcNat = "" Then
        valSrcNat = SetValSrcNat
    Else
        valSrcNat = Cells(elabrow, 11).Value
    End If

 stream.Write ("Rule" & valRuleNumber & Chr(13) & Chr(10))
 stream.WriteLine valInterface


 Next elabrow

stream.Close

fileexists:
    If Err.Number = 58 Then
     MsgBox "File already Exists"
    End If

 End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried filtering the data table.

Comment: could you show as the code you already have?

Comment: Add code in the orginal question, already tried to adapt a code with autofilter found here in the forum but without success

Comment: What's failing, where, and how?

Comment: just wrap your code inside the for next with  if  Cells(elabrow, 1).Value = 1 then .... and End IF

Comment: dear @harassed-dad: yep! that will be fine but the value of cells should be 1 for the first time, then it should be 2 and so on until it will reache the max value found in the 1st column (in this particular case it's 56)

Comment: 1 represents column A - are you saying the value isn't in column A?

Comment: Max value is returned by "maxRuleNumber = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("a:a"))"

Comment: dear @harassed-dad: sorry I meant Cells(elabrow, 1).Value = 1 should be Cells(elabrow, 1).Value = X, where X goes from 0 to the max value in the column A

Comment: ok, changed the code and now it works fine!